# Disk cloning fails due to wrong format

Tags: hard-drive

I am attempting to clone a 120gb Mac disk to a new 500gb hard disk. The hard disk has previously been used as an external disk on a PC, but has been reinitialised for Mac. However, it seems that no matter what method I use to clone (tried SuperDuper, CCC and Disk Utility), it seems as if the system thinks the disk is in the wrong format.

To test the 500gb disk, I put a clean install of Snow Leopard on it, and successfully booted another MacBook from it. At this point, I figured I had successfully ensured it would then be seen as a Mac disk when I cloned to it - but it wasn't. The software either doesn't see it at all or thinks it's formatted in Microsoft FAT32 format.

How can I fix this?

---

This from Disk Utility's log:

```
2012-10-28 11:13:26 +0000: Preparing to partition disk: “WDC WD50 00BPKT-00PK4T0 Media”
2012-10-28 11:13:26 +0000:  Partition Scheme: GUID Partition Table
2012-10-28 11:13:26 +0000:  1 volume will be created
2012-10-28 11:13:26 +0000: 
2012-10-28 11:13:26 +0000:  Partition 1
2012-10-28 11:13:26 +0000:      Name       : “Macintosh HD - new”
2012-10-28 11:13:26 +0000:      Size       : 465.8 GB
2012-10-28 11:13:26 +0000:      Filesystem : Mac OS Extended (Journaled)
2012-10-28 11:13:26 +0000: 
2012-10-28 11:13:26 +0000: Creating partition map.
2012-10-28 11:13:29 +0000: Formatting disk1s2 as Mac OS Extended (Journaled) with name Macintosh HD - new.
2012-10-28 11:13:39 +0000: Partition complete.
2012-10-28 11:13:39 +0000: 
**********
2012-10-28 17:25:50 +0000: Disk Utility started.
2012-10-28 17:26:57 +0000: Verifying volume “disk1s1” Starting verification tool:  2012-10-28 17:26:57 +0000
2012-10-28 17:26:57 +0000: Verify volume failed: Unrecognized Filesystem.
```

And this is what Disk Utility now reports:

```
Disk Description :  WDC WD50 00BPKT-00PK4T0 Media   Total Capacity :    465.8 GB (500,107,862,016 Bytes)
Connection Bus :    USB Write Status :  Read/Write
Connection Type :   External    S.M.A.R.T. Status : Not Supported
USB Serial Number : 000001D91811    Partition Map Scheme :  Master Boot Record
```

Comment: To make it easier to help you, can you please add a screenshot of the specific error message and the formats of the individual disks (via Disk Utility)?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear, but the problem is most likely to do with `Partition Map Scheme :  Master Boot Record` - this should be `Partition Scheme: GUID Partition Table` for a bootable OS X disk for a Mac with an Intel processor (the ones that have been sold by Apple for the last 6+ years).

The `Partition Map Scheme :  Master Boot Record` scheme is popular on Microsoft operating systems and can be used for disks that are not bootable on OS X and are required to just store data.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. If I put the 500GB disk in a MacBook, it boots, and DU reports it as a GUID disk. If I then attempt to copy to it from the machine whose hard disk I'm trying to upgrade (using an external USB disk is not recognised, and although DU sees it, it thinks it's a Master Boot Record disk.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for advice, I have now resolved this, using this tutorial:

http://www.macinstruct.com/node/130

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.